# Filtered DropDownList in GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview

I have `DropDownList` nested in `GridView`. How can I filter `DropDownList` data source, to show only active db rows (column Active as bit type) OR currently selected value of the `DropDownList`?

Where part of following code doesn't work. Is there some way how to bound to curent GridView row data (by the markup)?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="PlasticTypeId" 
    DataSourceID="dsPlasticTypes">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Active" HeaderText="Active" SortExpression="Active" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Labels, PlasticFamily %>" SortExpression="PlasticFamily.Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PlasticFamily.Name") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFamilies" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsFamilies" DataValueField="PlasticFamilyId"
                    DataTextField="Name" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PlasticFamilyId") %>'/>
                <asp:EntityDataSource ID="dsFamilies" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="name=PlasticsDbEntities" OrderBy="it.Name"
                    DefaultContainerName="PlasticsDbEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
                    EntitySetName="PlasticFamilies"
                    Where="it.Active==true || it.PlasticFamilyId==@control">
                    <WhereParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter Name="control" ControlID="ddlFamilies" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                    </WhereParameters>
                </asp:EntityDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I suggest you another solution, based on `DataView` and `RowFilter` link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Can you post in more detail about your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this by putting a hidden field above the DropDownList binded to the same field and using it as ControlParameter to filter data source.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Labels, PlasticFamily %>" SortExpression="PlasticFamily.Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PlasticFamily.Name") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPlasticFamilyId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("PlasticFamilyId") %>' />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFamilies" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsFamilies" 
            DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="PlasticFamilyId" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("PlasticFamilyId") %>' />
        <asp:EntityDataSource ID="dsFamilies" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="name=PlasticsDbEntities" 
            DefaultContainerName="PlasticsDbEntities" EnableFlattening="False" 
            EntitySetName="PlasticFamilies" OrderBy="it.Name" 
            Where="it.Active==true || it.PlasticFamilyId==@control">
            <WhereParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfPlasticFamilyId" Name="control" 
                    PropertyName="Value" Type="Int32" />
            </WhereParameters>
        </asp:EntityDataSource>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```